# How to Show Text in Two columns in JTextPane without using HTMLDocument?

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am using a JTextPane and want to show text in two columns for only a part of the content. I can't use HTML because I have to show an icon on the UI as well(I get an instance of javax.swing.Icon from an external API and I add it using StyleConstants.setIcon).

I need a layout like [this](http://www.lipsum.com/) but using a DefaultStyledDocument. Is this achievable? If so how can I do it?

Following is my code. I would like to have Paragraph2 and Paragraph3 side-by-side.

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    try
    {
      JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
      f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();

      URL url = new URL(
          "http://files.softicons.com/download/toolbar-icons/fatcow-hosting-icons-by-fatcow/png/32/status_online.png");
      BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);

      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);

      Document document = pane.getDocument();
      Style style = ((DefaultStyledDocument) document).addStyle("StyleName", null);
      StyleConstants.setIcon(style, icon);
      document.insertString(document.getLength(), "ignored text", style);

      document.insertString(document.getLength(),
          "\n\nParagraph 1. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. "
              + "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,"
              + " when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
              + " It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting",
          new SimpleAttributeSet());

      document.insertString(document.getLength(),
          "\n\nParagraph 2. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. "
              + "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,"
              + " when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
              + " It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting",
          new SimpleAttributeSet());

      document.insertString(document.getLength(),
          "\n\nParagraph 3. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. "
              + "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,"
              + " when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
              + " It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting",
          new SimpleAttributeSet());

      JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(pane);
      jScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

      f.getContentPane().add(
          jScrollPane,
          new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0,
              0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
      f.setSize(500, 400);
      f.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: http://java-sl.com/multicolumn.html or http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneTables.html you can use the last oen without border

Comment: @StanislavL thanks for the links. I thought that there would be a built in way to do this in a JEditorPane.

Comment: It does depend on Document instance so use a document where it's supported (like HTMLDocument) or implement it. The examples show how it could be implemented